# SQL Select Statement not working with 'like' as expected

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-like

The following query works as expected and doesn't return data with 'c' flag:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `func` 
WHERE  `next_act` < 1484870400
AND  `assigned_to` IS NULL
AND `type` like '%FTTC%'
AND  (`flags` NOT LIKE '%c%' OR `flags` IS NULL)
ORDER BY `priority`, `kci3_date`, `kci3_time` ASC
LIMIT 1
```

When I add an additional 'not like' it starts to return data with 'c' in `flags`

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `func` 
WHERE  `next_act` < 1484870400
AND  `assigned_to` IS NULL
AND `type` like '%FTCT%'
AND  (`flags` NOT LIKE '%c%' OR `flags` NOT LIKE 'w' OR `flags` IS NULL)
ORDER BY `priority`, `date`, `time` ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Well,  `flags NOT LIKE 'w'` allows `flags` to be *any* but `'w'` and `null` (`'c'` included)

Comment: I think you have to use AND not OR

Comment: write `AND  ((\`flags\` NOT LIKE '%c%' AND \`flags\` NOT LIKE 'w') OR \`flags\` IS NULL)` instead

Comment: What `flags` do you want to show?

Comment: it keeps returning `flags` with c despite the not like '%c%' ??

Comment: I want it to show any flags other than c, w or NULL

Comment: `(flags NOT LIKE '%c%' AND flags NOT LIKE 'w' AND flags IS NOT NULL)`

Comment: @fafl thanks, i'll add this and confirm if it works - just waiting on some data being populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used `OR` with a not like.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `func` 
WHERE  `next_act` < 1484870400
AND  `assigned_to` IS NULL
AND `type` like '%FTCT%'
AND  ((`flags` NOT LIKE '%c%' 
       AND `flags` NOT LIKE 'w' ) -- Should this be '%w%' ?
     OR `flags` IS NULL)
ORDER BY `priority`, `date`, `time` ASC
LIMIT 1
```

You can also use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `func` 
WHERE  `next_act` < 1484870400
AND  `assigned_to` IS NULL
AND `type` like '%FTCT%'
AND  (NOT (`flags` LIKE '%c%' 
       OR `flags` LIKE 'w' ) -- Should this be '%w%' ?
      OR `flags` IS NULL)
ORDER BY `priority`, `date`, `time` ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Saying (not like 'xxx' or not like 'yyy') means that 'xxx' is, in fact, not like 'yyy', so it will return the value.

Comment: Thanks for all the help - all working when switched to 'AND' instead of 'OR'

Answer (score 0):

You should combine conditions with `AND`, not with `OR`. According to your comment

> I want it to show any flags other than c, w or NULL

you want something like this:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM `func` 
   WHERE `next_act` < 1484870400
     AND `assigned_to` IS NULL
     AND `type` like '%FTCT%'
     AND  (`flags` <> 'c' AND 
           `flags` <> 'w' AND 
           `flags` IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY `priority`, 
         `date`, 
         `time` ASC
   LIMIT 1
```

Please, notice `NOT` in the `flags IS NOT NULL` and `flags <> 'w'` isntead of `LIKE ...`. You can combine both `<>` into single `NOT IN`:

```
     ...
   WHERE `next_act` < 1484870400
     AND `assigned_to` IS NULL
     AND `type` like '%FTCT%'
     AND  (`flags` NOT IN ('c', 'w') AND 
           `flags` IS NOT NULL)
     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It is returning data with 'c' because you are using or operator

```
`flags` NOT LIKE '%c%' OR `flags` NOT LIKE 'w`
```

It will check for both this condition and return row, please correct your query